# How can I list and edit all defined aliases in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

A friend who owned my current Mac before me created a lot of alias commands.  Is there a way to list all defined aliases and the command that is associated with them?

And if so, am I able to edit them or should I just remove them using unalias and recreate them?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

All you need to do is type `alias` at the prompt and any active aliases will be listed.

Aliases are usually loaded at initialization of your shell so look in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` in your home directory.

`unalias` will only work for your current session.  Unless you find where it is defined and loaded, it will be loaded again when you start a new Terminal session.

`~/.bashrc` gets run for both login and non-login shells, `~/.bash_profile` only gets run for login shells.

See [login shell vs non-login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/451)

**As per comment from Chris Page:**

You should put most of your customizations (including aliases) in `~/.bashrc` and have `~/.bash_profile` run `~/.bashrc`, so they apply to both login `(~/.bash_profile)` and non-login `(~/.bashrc)` shells. Also, decide which of these should be "primary" and if the **profile** is your choice, tack on the **rc** file at the end. If the **rc** file is primary, source that at the beginning of your **profile**

These lines should be in the file `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source $HOME/.bashrc
fi
```

This will include `~/.bashrc` for login shells and in the order you wish if one file depends upon the other based on what you are setting.

Comment: I recommend you put most of your customizations in ~/.bashrc and have ~/.bash_profile run ~/.bashrc, so they apply to both login (~/.bash_profile) and non-login (~/.bashrc) shells. e.g., put this in ~/.bash_profile: `if [ -f "$HOME"/.bashrc ]; then
    . "$HOME"/.bashrc
fi`

Answer (score 10):

You should have a look in these files:

```
/etc/profile
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
```

They are plausible startup files for your shell (that I assumed is bash).

Comment: ".bashrc" is the correct name of the file.

Comment: You're right, I don't why I wrote it like that.

Comment: I would have just edited it without comment, but StackExchange wouldn't let me make a one-character edit.

Comment: Also check in the system-wide /etc/bashrc

Comment: Dont forget all the files that are sourced using source or . (dot) in these files.

Comment: this is the correct answer for me, because I couldn't find my aliases in the standard ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, and was desperately searching for where they were defined. I forgot about ~/.profile, I stupidly put a couple aliases there and forgot all about them.

Comment: Sometimes, `~/.profile` is ignored if `~/.bash_profile` exists. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192521/loading-profile-from-bash-profile-or-not-using-bash-profile-at-all

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are usually stored in `.zshrc or .bash_profile or .bashrc` in your home directory.

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```