# is there a way to list all the aliases that point to a file or folder?

Tags: alias

I have a folder that I know I've made aliases of, but I need to find where those are.

Is there a way to list all the aliases that point to this folder?

Comment: If you’re using symlinks, then the second solution on [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948008/linux-command-to-list-all-available-commands-and-aliases) might be of use (since bash is available in OS X). This doesn’t cover standard OS X aliases, alas (although [this Ask Different question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25352/list-all-defined-aliases-in-terminal?rq=1) may be useful).

Comment: @AlexChan the AD question you linked focuses on bash aliases which is yet another thing :-)

Comment: @patrix does it? Whoops. /o\ I shouldn’t answer questions before I’ve woken up properly. ;)